# Umbraco Mediaservice outofmemory exception but file is uploaded

Tags: c#, umbraco, umbraco7, hangfire

I have added hangfire to process my file uploading to Media Folder as background process. Now my background process is uploading 1GB+ file size. Now it's working fine if the file is below 1GB but beyond that I'm getting an SystemOutOfMemoryException when it runs this code `ApplicationContext.Current.Services.MediaService.Save(media);`. Now I would assume that it did fail to create the file in the `media` folder but upon checking this folder it was able to move the file successfully to that folder it's just throwing a systemoutofmemory exception and that new files I can't see it when I login to the CMS->Media page. I'm not sure what to do here because the problem would be regardless if the file process succeed or not it successfully creates the Media folder. Now in my code it will assume it failed because of the exception so it tries to reprocess the file again which will duplicate and eats memory space.

Now my question is

1. why is it giving a `SystemOutOfMemoryException` when in fact it successfully moved the files to the media folder?
2. Since it failed to complete the process but successfully moved the files to the correct media directory (with correct autoid) how can I manually insert an entry to the DB to make it appear in the CMS?

Would appreciate your help. Below is my code

```
public string process()
    {
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "uploads");
        string lastFileName = "";

        foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
        {
            if (this.IsFileLocked(filePath)) {
                continue;
            }

            try
            {
                using (Stream stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePath))
                {
                    string filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                    lastFileName = filename;
                    //Constants.Conventions.MediaTypes.Image
                    string mediaType = Constants.Conventions.MediaTypes.File;
                    string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);

                    if (ext == ".jpg" || ext == ".png" || ext == ".gif" || ext == ".jpeg")
                    {
                        mediaType = Constants.Conventions.MediaTypes.Image;
                    }
                    HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(new HttpRequest(null, "https://www.google.com", null), new HttpResponse(null));
                    IMedia media = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.MediaService.CreateMedia(filename, Constants.System.Root, mediaType);
                    //IMedia media = Services.MediaService.CreateMedia(filename, Constants.System.Root, mediaType);
                    media.SetValue("umbracoFile", filename, stream);

                    // Save the media
                    ApplicationContext.Current.Services.MediaService.Save(media);
                    media = null;

                }
                System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
                Console.WriteLine($"{filePath} is deleted.");
                break;
            } catch (Exception e)  {
                Console.WriteLine($"{filePath} failed to process." + e.Message);
                return filePath + " failed to process " + e.Message;                    
            }
        }

        return lastFileName + " Process successful!";
    }
```

Note: This function is being called by hangfire background job that's why I mock the `HttpContext`

Answer (score 0):

My guess here is that if it's an image, it's falling over trying to generate thumbnail of the image for the back office. 1GB is a pretty big image to be uploading to a website, and resizing it to generate the thumbnail is likely to use a LOT of memory.

That said, I've had a site where CMS uses were uploading 1GB+ images fine, but that was hosted on a machine with a LOT of RAM, so running it out of memory would have taken some doing.

What version of Umbraco are you using, and what is the spec of the machine it's being hosted on?

Comment: Hi @Tim I just figured out the issue. I didn't have the problem with files less than 1GB regardless of file type as long as it's less than 1GB it's able to process it whether it's an image, zip or .mp4 file. I was able to find out that this `ApplicationContext.Current.Services.MediaService.Save(media)` code is causing it. The SystemOutOfMemory Exception is kinda misleading with the actual issue. I'll post my answer

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured out what was the issue after cracking my heads off for weeks and trying to configure the server to process large files. Turns out the server configuration and my local dev is sufficient enough to process large files. The issue to this is from this line

```
ApplicationContext.Current.Services.MediaService.Save(media)
```

Seems I'm not sure what's happening behind the scene here but for this kind of code it only works for files less than 1GB (I don't have sufficient proof to support this). But when I check the other available parameter it has other override which is down below

```
int user_id = 1;
int showError = false;
ApplicationContext.Current.Services.MediaService.Save(media, user_id, showError);
```

So based from this it has 2 more parameters that I can pass. The User_id and the ShowError. So basically my guess is it's trying to locate the user_id who uploaded the file but by default since I'm using a background service it doesn't have the user_id credential so "Maybe" it's trying to figure out who is the actual loggedin user but it can't find it because it's a background service request. Then there's the 3rd option which is ShowError. By default it's set to True so it's throwing the SystemOutOfMemory Exception when it encounters no user_id or probably it used up it's reserved memory trying to retry to figure the user_id.

Now I can't actually show proof that my "Guess" is actually correct but as soon as I added this 2 parameter it was able to save successfully and it didn't even take 2 seconds to process 1GB+ file.

Please feel free to comment if what it's actually doing specially the `MediaService.Save(media)` function.

Note: My request is from a background service being triggered by Hangfire. And I didn't encounter the error when I added the 2 optional parameter which is the UPLOADER/USERID and the SHOWERROR